# How to find time elapsed between two consecutive requests?

Tags: javascript

I have two checkboxes on selection of each one will raise a ajax request in order to get response from server. I need to call a method when there is atleast 2 seconds gap after the last request is made. Any idea? This means i do not want to call the methods when checkboxes are clicked continously for less than 2 seconds gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a timeout that will be activated in 2 seconds, and cancel it and restart it whenever someone clicks another checkbox.

```
var timeout;
var checkboxClickHandler = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          // Your logic.
    }, 2e3);
};
```

Comment: the above method would wait for 2 seconds after the checkboxes are clicked and executed the method for number of times the checkboxes are clicked. But i wanto cancel the request(dont call method) when the requests made within 2 seconds.

Comment: which means i wanto to execute the last request only.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeOut=0;
$(".selector").on('change',function(){
    if(timeOut == 0)
    {
        timeOut=2;  //change timeOut variable to "2" to be used in if condition above
        //your ajax request code ;  
        setTimeout(function(){timeOut=0},2000);   // changing back timeOut to 0 after 2 sec.
    }
});
```

Comment: take variable timeOut =0 then after triggering change event check value of timeOut if it is zero then execute your ajax request and change timeOut to 2 and after 2 sec change it back to 0 ,so that if change event trigger within 2 sec then it cant't passed thru if cond. & ajax call can't get executed

Answer (score 0):

If it is your server, which you call with ajax, you could set up a lock on on the server for the specific client (e.g. using a mysql table) with the pair of identification & time of the call. The next time a call is made, you check the table for recent calls. When a call is found and older than 2 seconds: delete it and proceed.
I could also think of a cookie solution, but stuff like this should be double checked on the server side always, since local code can be manipulated.